# curdate() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i'm looking to implement something that will give off called "curdate()" function when executed on mysql.

However the problem is, whenever i try to add "curdate()" as a function in PHP

```
$today = curdate();
```

It won't work (of course haha.)

So, my question (rephrased) is...

How do i make it so curdate() is a PHP function (rather than just an SQL one.)

---

I attempted to use

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
```

but for some reason it won't work, i need to add something i guess.

(As a side note, i'm using the "profile.class.php" file, so perhaps that'll explain why "$today = date("Y-m-d");" won't work.)

---

My Profile.class.php config

---

```
function add_viewed_me($member_id,$member_viewed)
{
                $time_now = date("Y-m-d");          

    $sql="insert into view_me";
    $sql.="(member_id";
    $sql.=", member_viewed";
    $sql.=", last_viewed_on";
    $sql.=", num_viewed)";
    $sql.=" values($member_id";
    $sql.=", $member_viewed";
    $sql.=", '$time_now'";
    $sql.=", 1)";

    $res=mysql_query($sql);

    if($res)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }           
}
```

Comment: "won't work"? date() will always work, unless you screw up the format string. perhaps you have a variable scoping issue, which is NOT php's problem.

Comment: @MarcB - you're right, my initial thought is to implement a "curdate()" function instead of the date one. However no matter how i try, it's impossible to impliment a curdate() function side a functions page.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: What do you mean when saying $today = date("Y-m-d"); don't work?

Comment: thanks for the update, i'll be sure to update all this. Until it's a mandatory thing in the future.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - i seriously have no clue, it won't work at all o.o it just shows http://dosha.re/i/KpQx.png

Comment: If you do like <?php $today = date("Y-m-d"); and then echo $today; ?> what happens?

Comment: What is the datatype where $time_now is set in the database? (Type of column in db)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - ironically i don't use the "echo" function in php at all. But it appears my column table was set inaccurately.

Comment: @Blahwhore - good that you've found the problem! :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - there is one thing that i am concerned about. When executing the "delete from view_me where last_viewed_on < date_sub(curdate(),interval 30 day)" function on mysql, it seems that it deletes everything from the database rather than delete things older than 30 days. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Try this instead: DELETE FROM view_me WHERE last_viewed_on < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

Comment: Make sure last_viewed_on is correct type also ;-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - I've executed what you told me, and it turns out that it somewhat works, should i use the "NOW()" function as an insert? (as in, avoid using curdate() at all costs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use MySQL's `CURDATE()` function; no need for PHP functions.

```
$sql="insert into view_me (member_id, member_viewed, last_viewed_on, num_viewed)
      values($member_id, $member_viewed, CURDATE(), 1)";
```

Comment: Nope, it returns "2013" only.

Comment: Try again. Was using a different DBMS function.

Comment: perhaps the way curdate is set o.o maybe the date("Y-m-d") is wrong.

Comment: @Blahwhore I'm not sure what you're doing. What is the data type of your `last_viewed_on` column?

Comment: it turns out i had the column set to "int(10)" so it didn't want to register "curdate()" accurately.

Answer (score 8):

You just want a PHP  function that returns the current date?

```
function curdate() {
    return date('Y-m-d');
}

// echo the date to screen
echo curdate();
```

EDIT:

You need to edit your query string directly:

`$sql.= ", CURDATE()";` instead of `$sql.=", '$time_now'";`

Comment: The PHP function is inside the functions page, i'll show you.

Comment: I've done so, but it returns the following "2013" Only. See: http://dosha.re/i/KpQx.png

Comment: Then your mysql column is probably formatted incorrectly. Make sure the column is the `DATE` type.

Comment: wow i'm an idiot haha, you're right. Though one more quick question. When selecting the "curdate()" function in mysql, it should be able to delete content older than 20 days right?

Example: [code]select count(*) as disney from view_me where last_viewed_on < date_sub(curdate(),interval 30 day)[/code]